# HPTLC Densitogram - Not Showing Other Secondary Metabolites

Tags: chromatography

I have run a HPTLC analysis of methanolic extract of Gymnema Sylvestre R.Br. plant in order to determine the concentration of active ingredient (Gymnemic acid using Gymnemagenin as standard). Sample run was outsourced to a third party. The densitogram of standard and sample are presented. Is it possible that other secondary metabolites do not appear as peak in the densitogram of the plant extract. In the result of the sample only the peak of the gymnemic acid appears while no other significant peak is witnessed indicating presence of other metabolites?.
[image: Gymnemagenin Standard]
[image: Densitogram of plant extract sample]

Comment: For readers, read about the anti-sweetener [Gymnemic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gymnemic_acid)